# How to register a 32-bit .DLL COM+ application on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, com+, dcom, dllregistration

I have read through all the similar questions but am not finding my exact problem answered. I have tried all the similar recommendations.

I am forced to migrate from a Windows Server 2003 environment to a Windows Server 2008 R2 environment running IIS 7.5.  I have a web application that calls COM objects in a 32-bit DLL.  The COM object was created from VB6.  Here is what I have done to date:

1. I have enabled 32-bit on my IIS Application Pool.
2. I have registered the .DLL and it's dependent .DLL using C:/windows/syswow64/regsvr32.exe -- the registration is successful.
3. I have verified that the .DLL and it's components are found in the registry using C:/windows/syswow64/regedit
4. I have created a COM+ object in Component Services (using syswow64/dcomcnfg) and started them.
5. I have created a role "Users" and added the group 'Everyone' to it.

When I run my application the web page hangs.  I can find the following error in the COM object's log file:

> ActiveX component can't create object   Error: [429]: CDataAdministrator::OpenCatalog

I have compared the setup between the new server and the old server.  One thing that I notice is that on the old server, the DataAdministrator object (DataAdministrator.CDataAdministrator) is listed under the expansion of DCOM Config, but on the new server it is not.  And I cannot seem to get it to show up there.

I have no errors in the event history or in IIS web logs.  To me it appears that everything is registered, but it won't run.  I can see a DLLHOST.EXE*32 in the task manager running under the account that I specified.

I'm at a loss here.... help?

Comment: From a vague memory, missing MSVBM50.DLL fixed by running MSVBM50.EXE. No idea whether it's your problem though. I scratched my head for ten minutes trying to get some VB6 stuff to run, gave up and rewrote it in C#, way easier than trying to wade through this lot.

Comment: Just for curiosity as not many people seem to use COM+... did you get a solution for your problem?

Comment: well i m having currently the same problem,  but am getting that the class is not registered.. ... did any one solved this?

Comment: well i figured it out, it seems u need to register ur 32 bit dll or .osx from the 64bit based reg64 found in here C:/windows/syswow64/regsvr32.exe just try removing it and adding it, it worked ...

Answer (score 3):

**Register 32 bit COM applications on a 64-bit server**

•Start...Run...C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mmc comexp.msc /32

As described here [http://msdn.microsoft.com...dcomcnfg.exe_and_64-bit_applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678426%28VS.85%29.aspx#dcomcnfg.exe_and_64-bit_applications)

Basically this runs the 32-bit version of dcomcnfg.exe so that you can set the DCOM settings for your 32-bit app on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled your application for x86 only?

Comment: Haven't got any other option in VB6, have they?

Comment: I'm talking about the web  application not the (VB6) COM dll.

Comment: The web application is mostly classic .ASP with calls to SQL Server database.  The last .ASP makes the call to the COM dll object.  The web app runs in an application pool that has 32-bit enabled.  How else would I force IIS 7.5 to compile the ASP in 32-bit?