# can't install WDDX library on windows 2008 r2 for asp

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a classic asp application that takes advantage of WDDX libraries on Windows 2003.  We are trying to update to Windows 2008r2.   We aren't updating to Windows 2012 for separate reasons.

We use this library on Windows 2003 http://www.finwin.com/Dev/wddxsdk/2__Software_Libraries/Installation.html#COM.

I installed this same library on Windows 2008.   I was able to run command "regsvr32 wddx_com.dll" without errors.   Yet, when we run the app we are receiving the error " ActiveX component can't create object" on the line "set objExtranetWDDX = server.createobject("WDDX.Recordset")".

Comment: This question might be better posted to serverfault, rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks,  Here is the question on ServerFault   http://serverfault.com/q/725908/314205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this post might have the answer you are looking for

[how-to-register-a-32-bit-dll-com-application-on-windows-2008-r2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11525117/462121)