# VB6 dll will not install on server 2012r2

Tags: vb6, 32bit-64bit, windows-server-2012-r2, com+

I am trying to install a new dll created in VB6 via the component services wizard for a legacy application. 
It all appears to have worked correctly until I try to access the relevant asp webpage and I get a server 500 error.
Checking the event log shows the following:

> A registry value was changed while installing the following component
>   into a COM+ Application. If you are experiencing activation problems
>   with this component then please check the registry value for the
>   following key.
>
> ```
> Component: dllpath\mydll.dll
>
> Registry Key: CLSID\{D5DE8D20-5BB8-11D1-A1E3-00A0C90F2731}\InProcServer32
>
> Process Name: RunDll32.exe Comsvcs.dll file version:  not loaded
> ```

I've been digging around trying to find a solution and as I understand it this is being caused by me trying to put a 32bit dll on a 64bit OS... though correct me if I'm wrong.

So far I've tried:

Using elevated command prompt:

```
REGSVR32 "mydll.dll"
```

Gives an error message "The module "mydll" may not be compatible with the version of windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an x86 (32-bit) or x64(64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe"

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\REGSVR32 "mydll.dll"
```

Message pops up to say this has been successful, however the component does not show in component services and the server 500 error still comes up.

Adding it via MMC -32 using the component services snap in doesn't work either.

I also found [this](https://techtalk.gfi.com/32bit-object-64bit-environment/) but as someone who knows next to nothing about amending registry keys I'm not keen to try it out.

What's really odd about this is I made a change to this system ~6m ago and added two new dlls in the same way without any issues.

Any help or ideas appreciated.

EDIT:
The dll I am trying to add is an update to one I had edited ~6m ago without issue and I am also getting the same error messages when I try to reinstall this version.

Dev env - Windows Server 2003 VM with VB 6.0

Comment: Maybe you are trying to use the 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit process? Though if this is a legacy application which already uses other similar VB6 DLLs that doesn't' seem likely.

Comment: Why not create a new DLL with .net and call from ASP? Here is a link show how to do that. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12408/Call-a-NET-component-from-an-ASP-Page

Comment: @Sarah, is this the same problem you are having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369743/how-to-register-a-32-bit-dll-com-application-on-windows-2008-r2

Comment: BTW based on some google the GUID `D5DE8D20-5BB8-11D1-A1E3-00A0C90F2731` appears to be referencing C:\Windows\system32\msvbvm60.dll which is the VB6 runtime.

Comment: Thanks Dave yes thats a similar issue, I've tried out the answer there - no luck. Everything I've been able to find on this issue suggests its 32v64 though as you guessed this is a legacy app which all dlls have been created the same way so I'm at a loss to explain it.

Comment: VB6 seems like a lifetime ago, but is your DLL being built with maintaining Binary Compatibility? If so, you shouldn't need to re-register the .DLL?

Comment: Well as much as I hate to admit it, the problem here was... me. I fixated on this error having forgotten I had also made a small change to the asp page - that was causing the error, the dll was in fact installing correctly. Sorry for wasting your time folks!